# Intersect two boolean arrays for True

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Having the numpy arrays

```py
a = np.array([ True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
b = np.array([False,  True,  True,  True,  False], dtype=bool)
```

How can I make the intersection of the two so that only the `True` values match? I can do something like:

```py
a == b    # array([False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

but the last item is `True` (understandably because both are `False`), whereas I would like the result array to be `True` only in the 4th element, something like:

```
array([False, False, False,  True,  False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: `np.logical_and`

Comment: Okay, so that's three comments so far which should be answers and not comments, two of which are wrong.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Numpy provides [`logical_and()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) for that purpose:

```
a = np.array([ True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
b = np.array([False,  True,  True,  True,  False], dtype=bool)

c = np.logical_and(a, b)
# array([False, False, False, True, False], dtype=bool)
```

More at [Numpy Logical operations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html#logical-operations).

Comment: Sweet. I wasn't aware of the `np.logical_and()`, until now. That works as intended. a `and` b as suggested in the comments to the question doesn't work.

Comment: @PedroA `and`, `not` and `or` won't work because of the way Python deals with logical operations which NumPy cannot override (except in expressions). However, you can get XOR with the common `a != b`.

Comment: On bool arrays, you can also use `&` as a shortcut for `logical_and`, `|` as a shortcut for `logical_or`, and `^` as a shortcut for `logical_xor`.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like if there are only two arrays, `&` (or even `*`) is more straightforward.

```py
c = a & b                   # array([False, False, False,  True, False])
c = a * b                   # array([False, False, False,  True, False])
```

Also, `np.all()` may be called row-wise (`axis=0`) on the list of the arrays.

```py
c = np.all([a, b], axis=0)  # array([False, False, False,  True, False])
```

Also if there are many arrays that needs to be reduced into a single array, `logical_*` methods can be reduced (e.g. `np.logical_and.reduce()`).

```py
a = np.array([ True, False, False,  True, False])
b = np.array([False,  True,  True,  True,  False])
c = np.array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True])
d = np.array([True,  True,  True,  True,  True])

x = np.logical_and.reduce([a, b, c, d])    # array([False, False, False,  True, False])
y = np.all([a, b, c, d], axis=0)
z = a & b & c & d
```