# how do i conduct an if statement using a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am attempting to create a program to read from a csv file and then to convert the times in the file to a numpy array to be questioned by an if statement as follows:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

currentdate = date.today()

sevendaysago = currentdate - timedelta(days=7)

readings = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Csaba\Downloads\BloodGlucoseData.csv')

blood_glucose_readings = readings["Historic Glucose mmol/L"]

dates_and_times = readings["Device Timestamp"]

reading_times_hours = dates_and_times.str.slice(10, 16)

reading_times = np.array(reading_times_hours)

reading_dates = dates_and_times.str.slice(0, 10)

morning_reading = 0

for reading in reading_times:
    if reading_times <= "4:00" and reading_times >= "11:00":
        morning_reading = morning_reading + 1

else:
    morning_reading = morning_reading
```

however I continue to get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Csaba\Documents\Python\Glucose Control Recommendation program.py", line 24, in <module>
    if reading_times <= "4:00" and reading_times >= "11:00":
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

any help appreciated thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intersect two boolean arrays for True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578571/intersect-two-boolean-arrays-for-true)

Comment: What are you expecting this to do: `for reading in reading_times:` You never actually use `reading` in the loop?

Comment: I was hoping to loop through each reading in the reading_times array but wasn’t sure of the exact code to do so, probably a bit too complex a project for a beginner in python but I’ve learned a lot since I started it

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating on `reading_times` you should use `reading` in the if statement, not `reading_times`:

```
for reading in reading_times:
    if reading <= "4:00" and reading >= "11:00":
```

`reading_times` is an array, and so is `reading_times <= "4:00"`.  Print that to see for yourself.  An array like that can't be used in an `if` statement, nor with an `and`.

Is the indentation of the `else:` part right?