# Vectorising looped numpy arrays with conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I'm translating some scientific/teaching C-code to Python, which uses loops on arrays leading to a large slowdown (~10x) when the arrays get large. I have attempted to move away from loops but I'm having trouble reproducing the logic in the original algorithm.

Here is a "straightforward" translation, where I want to get the sum of the differences and compare them to some float values. All `eps_*` vars are `float` values.

`is_feasible` is an `n_pop`-length `bool` array. `obj` is an `[a, n_pop]`-shape array.

```
is_feasible = np.all(con <= -eps_vio, axis=0)  # len(is_feasible) == n_pop == con.shape[1]
rank = np.ones(n_pop, dtype=int)

for n in range(n_pop):
    for m in range(n_pop):

        is_dominant = True

        # Condition 1
        if is_feasible[n] and is_feasible[m]:
            d_obj = obj[:, n] - obj[:, m]
            if (d_obj < -eps_dom).any():  # --> ndarray.any()
                is_dominant = False
            d_obj_sum = d_obj.sum()

            if is_dominant and d_obj_sum <= -eps_dom:
                is_dominant = False

        # Condition 2
        elif not is_feasible[n] and not is_feasible[m]:
            d_vi = np.maximum(con[:, n], 0) - np.maximum(con[:, m], 0)
            d_vi_sum = d_vi.sum()

            if d_vi_sum < -eps_dom:
                is_dominant = False

        else:
            is_dominant = False

        if is_dominant:
            rank[n] += 1
```

Rather than looping through the population twice to get the differences, I tried to find where possible `is_feasible` combinations are `True` using [meshgrid](https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-get-all-element-combinations-of-two-numpy-arrays-in-python) and [logical_and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578571/intersect-two-boolean-arrays-for-true) to find a mask for condition 1. So far, I have:

```
is_feasible = np.all(con <= -eps_vio, axis=0)
rank = np.ones(n_pop, dtype=int)

# Get every combination of pairs of feasibility into 2 columns
feas_mesh = np.array(np.meshgrid(is_feasible, is_feasible))
combinations = feas_mesh.T.reshape(-1, 2)  # shape: [len(is_feasible) ** 2, 2]

is_dominant = np.ones(n_pop, dtype=bool)

# For each pair, if both true or both false, do different checks for dominance
# Condition 1 mask
feas_pairs = combinations[:, 0] & combinations[:, 1]  # == np.logical_and()
```

-but I'm having trouble working out how to get the row-wise difference of `obj` (2-D, rather than 1-D `is_feasible`) on which to apply the `feas_pairs` mask. I thought I could try the meshgrid technique again on `obj` to but I couldn't get my head around how to `reshape` the and extract only the row-wise values.

i.e. with an example `obj`, where `n_pop=3`:

```
obj = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)                                                                                                                                                        
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5]])

b = np.array(np.meshgrid(obj, obj)).T.reshape(-1, 2)  # what to reshape to for easy selection?
# array([[0, 0],
#        [0, 1],
#        [0, 2],
#        [0, 3],
#        [0, 4],
#        [0, 5],
#        [1, 0],
#        [1, 1],
#        [1, 2],
#        [1, 3],
#        [1, 4],
#        [1, 5],
#        [2, 0],
#        [2, 1],
#        [2, 2],
#        [2, 3],
#        [2, 4],
#        [2, 5],
#        [3, 0],
#        [3, 1],
#        [3, 2],
#        [3, 3],
#        [3, 4],
#        [3, 5],
#        [4, 0],
#        [4, 1],
#        [4, 2],
#        [4, 3],
#        [4, 4],
#        [4, 5],
#        [5, 0],
#        [5, 1],
#        [5, 2],
#        [5, 3],
#        [5, 4],
#        [5, 5]])
```

However, this is only a problem I need to solve if we go down this route.
Is there a better approach to the main problem? Thanks and let me know if I can clarify this question.

Comment: If you already have C-Code you can translate it to Numba Cython (more or less syntax changes (you can keep loopy code), but no logical ones like vectorization). Of course simple wrapping the C-Code is also a possibility, but I guess that's not the question.

Comment: Thanks, @max9111 - that is one approach but I wanted to keep it in Python, if possible, to keep things simple for other students who demo the code =)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the solution I came up with was to flatten the entire double loop into an array of `combinations`. It runs in a fraction of the time of the original looped Python version (only a few times slower than the original C code) but I'm not entirely sure that it is nearly as readable anymore! I guess that the tradeoff is required in this case for reasonable runtimes.

To make it easier to keep track of the bools in `is_dominant`, this was also increased in size to match the meshgrid `combinations`. A `reshape` at the end is used to mimic the inner loop and count up the bools for `rank[n]`. Any suggestions and improvements are welcome!

```
is_feasible = np.all(con <= -eps_vio, axis=0)  # len(is_feasible) = con.shape[1]
rank = np.ones(n_pop, dtype=int)

# Get every combination of index pairs of feasibility into 2 columns
feas_mesh = np.array(np.meshgrid(is_feasible, is_feasible))
combinations = feas_mesh.T.reshape(-1, 2)  # shape: [len(is_feasible) ** 2, 2]

# Check condition 1. For each pair, filter mask for both True
feas_pairs = combinations[:, 0] & combinations[:, 1]  # == np.logical_and(), len(is_feasible)**2
is_dominant = np.zeros(n_pop ** 2, dtype=bool)

d_objs_sum = np.zeros(np.count_nonzero(feas_pairs))
is_dom_i = np.ones(np.count_nonzero(feas_pairs), dtype=bool)
for i in range(n_obj):
    # For each objective, flatten every possible combination
    d_obj_mesh = np.array(np.meshgrid(obj[i, :], obj[i, :]))
    d_obj_combinations = d_obj_mesh.T.reshape(-1, 2)
    d_obj_combinations = d_obj_combinations[feas_pairs, :]  # Filter out feasible pairs
    d_obj = d_obj_combinations[:, 0] - d_obj_combinations[:, 1]  # shape: n_pop ** 2
    is_dom = d_obj >= -eps_dom  # Check for dominance
    # Only remains True if is_dom for all n_obj
    is_dom_i[:] = np.logical_and(is_dom_i, is_dom)
    d_objs_sum += d_obj  # Sum for separate check below

is_dominant[feas_pairs] = np.logical_or(is_dominant[feas_pairs], is_dom_i)
is_dom = d_objs_sum > -eps_dom
is_dominant[feas_pairs] = np.logical_and(is_dominant[feas_pairs], is_dom)  # must pass this and previous test - logical_and

# Check condition 2. For each pair, filter mask for both False
infeas_pairs = ~combinations[:, 0] & ~combinations[:, 1]  # len(is_feasible)**2
d_vis_sum = np.zeros(np.count_nonzero(infeas_pairs))
for i in range(n_con):
    d_vi_mesh = np.array(np.meshgrid(con[i, :], con[i, :]))
    d_vi_combinations = d_vi_mesh.T.reshape(-1, 2)
    d_vi_combinations = d_vi_combinations[infeas_pairs, :]  # Filter for infeasible pairs
    d_vi = np.maximum(d_vi_combinations[:, 0], 0) - np.maximum(d_vi_combinations[:, 1], 0)
    d_vis_sum += d_vi

is_dom = d_vis_sum >= -eps_dom
is_dominant[infeas_pairs] = np.logical_or(is_dominant[infeas_pairs], is_dom)

# Count up is_dominant after reshape
# i.e. n rows and m columns as in looped version
# is_dominant.reshape(3, 3)
# array([[True, False, False],
#        [False, False, False],
#        [True, False, True]])
#
# np.count_nonzero(is_dominant.reshape(3, 3), axis=1)
# array([1, 0, 2])
rank_up = np.count_nonzero(is_dominant.reshape(n_pop, n_pop), axis=1)
rank += rank_up
```